# Ending a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I've about got down how to open a `fragment`. Here is my predicament. I have a list of the elements (periodic table elements) that is next to my `view`. When you select an element it shows it's information.

My problem is that I need to be able to remove the `view` from the (what we'll call details fragment) and remove it from the stack that way I don't have a huge memory backup.

How do I remove it from the stack when a new `fragment` is called to replace it?

Comment: Is having "a huge memory backup" really an issue? Unless it's causing you actual problems, or you have information that suggests it will be an issue, you're adding needless complexity to your application.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove a fragment using the `#remove()` method of `FragmentTransaction`. This method also removes the view from the container it has been attached to.

However, from the fragments documentation:

> Stopped:
>   The fragment is not visible. Either the host activity has been stopped or the fragment has been removed from the activity but added to the back stack. A stopped fragment is still alive (all state and member information is retained by the system). However, it is no longer visible to the user and will be killed if the activity is killed.

If you've added that fragment to the back stack it is not going to be killed until the activity gets killed.

Comment: Are not there anyway to kill fragment on activity?? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try disallowing add to backstack. That when when a fragment is removed, or replaced, it doesnt get added to the backstack and it would need to be repopulated again( with data).